# Selecting dynamic no. of columns using select Query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Suppose there is a table(**TB_dynamic_date**) with column_name as '**Data_to_select**'

Lets say there is another table **TB_Main_Data** with column names
as **Name,DOJ,id**

So , Is it possible to write a query in a way ,through which i can fetch dynamic no. of columns from **TB_Main_Data**,using the table **TB_dynamic_date**
where **TB_dynamic_data**  contains the following records under '**Data_to_select**' as string

```
1)Name,DOJ
2)Name,id
3)Name,id,DOJ
4)Name,id,DOj,Name||id
```

What i need to do is  something like the following:-

```
select **(1/2/3/4 record from TB_dynamic_data)** from TB_Main_Data
```

I Hope, i was able to explain clearly , what i want to ask.

Comment: You can do this with dynamic SQL (execute immediate) but not with a simple query.

Comment: But How?? Can you Please give an example

Comment: Gordon any updates???

Comment: Dynamic sql can be generated and executed only in PL/SQL. Write an anonymous block, prepare the query dynamically, concatenate it with the variables you declared and assigned for the column names or values.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, this would look like:

```
declare
    v_columns varchar(4000);
    v_sql varchar(4000);
begin
    select data_to_selecct
    into v_columns
    from tb_dynamic_data
    where <whatever>;

    v_sql := 'select ' || v_columns || ' from tb_main_data';
    execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic query like below

```
Declare @cols= ( select Data_to_select from TB_Dynamic_data where Id=2)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)  
Set @query = ' select '  + @cols + ' from TB_main_data'

Exec(@query)
```